# Are there any published games of Bobby Fischer as world champion?

Tags: chess

Between the World Championship Match against Spassky in 1972 and his rematch against Spassky in 1992, Bobby Fischer played no tournament games, [not even to defend his title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Fischer#Forfeiture_of_title).

Are there *any* published games in existence played by Fischer during this period?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Chessgames.com has three games Fischer played against the Greenblatt computer program](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?page=38&pid=19233&eresult=).

Those seems to be the only games of Fischer available online during this time period. There don't appear to be any copies online of Fischer's five minute 1981 games with Peter Biyiasas.

Comment: People don't normally annotate their moves in blitz :\